# Ubuntu 12.04 automatically boots, no GRUB menu

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, windows-7

I have a Dell Inspirion 531 running Windows 7 and I installed Ubuntu in a dual boot side-by-side setup, but it boots directly into Ubuntu 12.04.

I have run the Ubuntu boot repair disk, but with no success.

There is one message before Ubuntu loads. `Kvm not accessible` (or something like that).

The boot repair run [is here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6692977/).

Comment: i figured out the grub menu is beneath the "screen resolution not opt level" I am able to boot into windows by using the down arrows a few times, hit enter even though i can't see it. I have yet to figure out how to set resolution at higher level. I'll try updating the nvideo drivers though i don't need unity.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the time out interval to boot into windows.

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

change

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
```

to

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=7
```

then save and run:

```
 sudo update-grub
```

then reboot

Comment: i went to gedit and noticed that the timeout=10, so i don't think thats what is hanging me up. thank you, any other advice much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Grub Customizer to change the resolution of the Grub menu. You should then be able to see the Windows option.

1) Open Grub Customizer

2) Go to Appearance settings tab

3) Check (tick mark) custom resolution and enter your screen resolution value.
Example: 1280x1024

4) Click save

5) Choose Install to MBR under File Menu

6) Reboot

To install Grub Customizer, run the following commands in a terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer          

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```